# How do I move N number of files from a directory, where N is very large? Mac OSX

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have 2 million image files (on the order of kb) in one directory, but I need to move them into 4 separate directories.   How can I do this on a Mac OS terminal?  I see others posting for GNU, and usually not for a lot of files.  I don't mind moving N number of files, 4 times to get the job done.

Thanks!

Comment: Any logic to which file goes to which directory? Is "Move 3 files to one directory each and everything else to the fourth directory" equally satisfactory as "Split alphabet into four quarters and move files according to the first letter"? There's no end to the number of strategies one could imagine; please be more specific.

Comment: No logic at all, any file can go into another directory.  However, I will eventually make the files evenly split between the 4 directories, roughly.

Comment: The size of the files is irrelevant when moving them.

Comment: Hash the names of the files into 4 buckets.  Move them into the appropriate directory.

Comment: Or, more likely, just do it round robin.

Comment: Loop through the files, rotating the destination directory for each file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mkdir -p dir{0,1,2,3}
$ i=0; for f in *; do test -f "$f" && mv "$f" dir$((i++ % 4)); done
```